# How to deal with NestJS circular dependency when using dynamic modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to make a NestJS Library for an API I want to access. I split it off into its own library where the main module is a dynamic module that takes the baseUrl for the server it will be connecting to. I then have a second "child" api-section module that will actually be making the api calls. I need a way to pass that baseUrl into the api-section while also exporting the api-section service from the api-library to use in the main apps app.module. The modules are split this way since there will be many "child" modules to access different parts of the API as its very big.

Currently this leads to a circular dependency issue, with the cli suggesting I use a forwardRef. I've tried adding a forwardRef to both the ApiSectionModule import in ApiLibraryModule and vice versa but that leads to another error "TypeError: metatype is not a constructor"

I feel like this whole thing is just the wrong overall pattern, but not sure how else to approach it.

Sample repo:
https://github.com/computebender/libsample

Comment: If you're running into circular dependencies, you should maybe rethink your structure and dependencies. Maybe find out exactly what the library has to provide, and then pull that out to a second file, instead of the library also being the main module. It's also a bit hard to comprehend exactly where the issue stems from, from your description and the repo. Maybe include code snippets from the files involved in the issue for us to understand it better.

Comment: @Phoenix1355 The library has a main module that gets configured with the base url (api-library.module.ts) I want this module to import then re-export all the other modules (api-section.module.ts) that have services (api-section.service.ts). Then in my main app (app.module.ts) I want to import ApiLibraryModule and have access to all the services ApiSectionModule provides. The main thing I'm trying to avoid is having api-library.module.ts provide like 100 services, that just seems messy (since there will probably be 10 modules like api-section.module.ts each with 10 services)